# Show progress when getting list items from SharePoint List

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Now I have a jQuery function for getting the list items from SharePoint List

```
function getListItems(listTitle, queryText){ 
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var splist =  ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);  
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(queryText);
    var listItems = splist.getItems(camlQuery);

    ctx.load(listItems); 

    var d = $.Deferred();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
       var result = listItems.get_data().map(function(i){
           return i.get_fieldValues();   
       });
       d.resolve(result);
    },
    function(sender,args){
       d.reject(args);
    });
    return d.promise();
}
```

And then I call this function

```
getListItems(listname , "").done(function(listItems){
      //do something here...
}).fail(function(error){console.log(error.get_message());}); // Error message
```

But one of the list contains quite a large amount of records and I want to show the progress to users so that they know what is going on. Is there a way to do this with just client side scripting? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the provided example you could display only *indeterminate* progress bar since the request is submitted once to the server and there is no way to determine current status complete.

But since SharePoint JSOM API supports **paged** data retrieval, you could consider the below approach that allows to determine current status complete and therefore display *determinate* progress bar.

```
function getPagedListItems(list, queryText,itemsCount,position){
    itemsCount = itemsCount || 100; 
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list =  ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var ctx = list.get_context();  
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    if(typeof position != 'undefined')
        camlQuery.set_listItemCollectionPosition(position);
    var viewXml = String.format("<View>{0}<RowLimit>{1}</RowLimit></View>",queryText,itemsCount);
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(viewXml);
    var listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    ctx.load(list, 'ItemCount'); 
    ctx.load(listItems); 

    var d = $.Deferred();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
       d.resolve(listItems,list.get_itemCount());
    },
    function(sender,args){
       d.reject(args);
    });
    return d.promise();
}

function getListItems(listTitle, queryText,itemsCount,position,results){
    results = results || [];
    return getPagedListItems(listTitle, queryText,itemsCount,position)
   .then(function(pagedItems,totalItemCount){
       pagedItems.get_data().filter(function(i){
           results.push(i.get_fieldValues());   
       }); 
       var percentLoaded = results.length / totalItemCount * 100;
       console.log(String.format('{0}% has been loaded..',percentLoaded));
       var pos = pagedItems.get_listItemCollectionPosition();
       if(pos != null) {
           return getListItems(listTitle, queryText,itemsCount,pos,results);
       }    
       return results;     
   });
}
```

**Usage**

```
var listTitle = 'Contacts';
getListItems(listTitle , "",20)
.done(function(results){
     console.log('Completed');
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(error.get_message());
});
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer: You can't**

Since your query is executed as a single request, there's no way to show "real" progress, although you could fake it by showing a generic "loading" gif.

**Long Answer: You can if you really want to**

If you were to modify your query to be paged (with a row limit per query), and then execute one request per page until all records are loaded, then you could update something on the page indicating progress.

```
// Use the RowLimit element to query for only 100 items at a time
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View>" 
    + "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Created\" /></OrderBy>"
    + "<RowLimit>100</RowLimit>"
    + "</View>");
```

Now inside the onSuccess function of `executeQueryAsync()`, you can access the `listItemCollectionPosition` property of your list item collection and pass that back into your CAML query to get the next page of items.

```
var itemsCount = listItems.get_count();
// use itemCount to update the current progress as displayed to the user

camlQuery.set_listItemCollectionPosition(listItems.get_listItemCollectionPosition());
// set the query's listItemCollectionPosition so you'll get the next page of results

// reload the items with the updated query
listItems = splist.getItems(camlQuery);
ctx.load(listItems);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(... // rinse and repeat to get the next batch of items
```

Obviously, this approach would require you to restructure your code to allow an arbitrary number of function calls. You may want to split out your onSuccess function into a named function instead of an anonymous one, so you can execute it somewhat recursively.

When you restructure your code, I also recommend wrapping the entire code block up inside an immediately executing function expression so that your variables can be accessed as needed without polluting the global namespace.

```
(function(){
    //your code here
})();
```